# Get Types from assembly loaded by UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-assembly, .net-native

I am wondering what is the best way to get the types defined in assemblies referenced by a UWP application (.Net Native compiled).

I am using an IOC container and like to register the types based on a convention.

```
Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MainPage))
    .DefinedTypes
    .Where(t => t.IsClass && t.IsPublic)
    .ToList()
```

The above code only gives me the types defined in the UWP applications and not the referenced assemblies.

#### UPDATE

I am able to get the types from the referenced assembly if I know the name

```
var types = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("Simple")).ExportedTypes.ToList();
```

However, I am not able to discover the loaded assemblies. The statement below throws an exception.

```
var names = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MainPage)).GetReferencedAssemblies();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following is a way to get all the referenced assemblies. Hope it will be useful to you. You can further loop the assemblies to get the Type OR other required stuff. It will fetch all the DLL and EXE files from the location where your app is installed.

You can check this is with the Debug and Release both modes for the difference.

```
public static async Task<List<Assembly>> GetReferecedAssemblies()
{
    List<Assembly> refAssemblies = new List<Assembly>();

    var allFiles = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFilesAsync();
    var filteredFiles = allFiles.Where(file => file.FileType == ".dll" || file.FileType == ".exe");

    if (filteredFiles != null && filteredFiles.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var file in filteredFiles)
        {
            try
            {
                refAssemblies.Add(Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(file.DisplayName)));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }

    return refAssemblies;
}
```

**OUTPUT** from Immediate Window

```
Count = 103
    [0]: {App1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null}
    [1]: {Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a}
    [2]: {Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a}
    [3]: {Microsoft.Win32.Primitives, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a}
    [4]: {System.AppContext, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a}
    [5]: {System.Collections.Concurrent, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a}
    [6]: {System.Collections, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a}
    [7]: {System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.1.37.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a}
    [8]: {System.Collections.NonGeneric, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a}
    [9]: {System.Collections.Specialized, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a}
    // more here...
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, hangs at `Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFilesAsync()`

Comment: please check your async and await calls implementation. I tested this code and then pasted here. Its working for me. What error it shows?

Comment: I corrected the issue, it required `.GetFilesAsync().AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false)` at the end. However, I am seeing strange behaviour, the method returns 3 files and 2 of them are the main UWP app (one as dll and other as exe). Anyway, the dll is still not returned. So still can't get the type. I am not sure if it is something to do with default.rd.xml

Comment: I put my output in answer. It returns me a long list of assemblies.

Comment: One thing you can try is that first DEPLOY your app(right clicking project in solution) and then DEBUG. Try this and let me know

Comment: Are you sure you are using .Net Native Compilation in release. My sln consists of Default UWP created using VS 2017 15.6.7 targetting 16299 build. It is referencing a Sample.csproj (a .NET Standard 2.0 dll). I will upload my app to github shortly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170081/discussion-between-resp78-and-gaurang-dave).